# save and load fine-tuned bert classification model using tensorflow 2.0

Tags: nlp, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model

I am trying to save a fine-tuned binary classification model based on pretrained Bert module 'uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12'. I'm using tf2.

The code set up the model structure:

```
bert_classifier, bert_encoder =bert.bert_models.classifier_model(bert_config, num_labels=2)
```

then:

```
# import pre-trained model structure from the check point file
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model=bert_encoder)
checkpoint.restore(
    os.path.join(gs_folder_bert, 'bert_model.ckpt')).assert_consumed()
```

then: I compiled and fit the model

```
bert_classifier.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss=loss,
    metrics=metrics)

bert_classifier.fit(
      Text_train, Label_train,
      validation_data=(Text_val, Label_val),
      batch_size=32,
      epochs=1)
```

at last: I saved the model in the model folder which then automatically generates a file named saved_model.pb within

```
bert_classifier.save('/content/drive/My Drive/model')

also tried this:

tf.saved_model.save(bert_classifier, export_dir='/content/drive/My Drive/omg')
```

now I try to load the model and apply it on test data:

```
from tensorflow import keras

ttt = keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/model')
```

I got:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-93f80aa585da> in <module>()
----> 1 tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath='/content/drive/My Drive/omg', custom_objects={'Transformera':bert_classifier})

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _revive_graph_network(self, metadata, node_id)
    392     else:
    393       model = models_lib.Functional(
--> 394           inputs=[], outputs=[], name=config['name'])
    395 
    396     # Record this model and its layers. This will later be used to reconstruct

KeyError: 'name'
```

This error message doesn't help me with what to do...please kindly advice.

I also tried to save the model in h5 format, but when i load it

```
ttt = keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/model.h5')
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-12f76139ec24> in <module>()
----> 1 ttt = keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/model.h5')

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    294   cls = get_registered_object(class_name, custom_objects, module_objects)
    295   if cls is None:
--> 296     raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
    297 
    298   cls_config = config['config']

ValueError: Unknown layer: BertClassifier
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems as if you have the answer right in the question: `'/content/drive/My Drive/model'` will fail due to the whitespace character.

You could try it with escaping the backspace: `'/content/drive/My\ Drive/model'`.

Other option, after I had exactly the same problem with saving and loading. What helped was to just save the weights of the pre-trained model and not saving the whole model:

Just take a look right here: https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/, especially at the methods `save_weights()` and `load_weights()`.